# How to have relative path for Microsoft Access Driver(.mdb) file

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="localconnection" connectionString="Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=D:/abc/pqr/xyz/abc.mdb; UID=;PWD=12345;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

**Question:** How can i pass relative path for (.mdb) file in web.config file? I tried using (../) and  (~/) but its not working. Can any one please help me out.

Comment: You should try \\

Comment: I would start with using \ backslashes instead of '/' forward slashes. I assume the relative path should start from the working directory of the process that might not be at the root your webapplication but one level higher. So you would need `DBQ=.\nameofwebapp\data\abc,mdb`. You can use [process monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) and filter on errors. That should show you which path is tried for your abc.mdb file.

Comment: Note that the working directory of a process can be set to anything. If it is set on C:\windows\system32 there is no relative path to D:\

Comment: @FaizanRabbani, @ rene i tried both the ways but still not working its showing me following error  ERROR [IM006] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's SQLSetConnectAttr failed
ERROR [01000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]General Warning Unable to open registry key 'Temporary (volatile) Jet DSN for process 0x713c Thread 0x71dc DBC 0x35cfc204 Jet'.
ERROR [01000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]General Warning Unable to open registry key 'Temporary (volatile) Jet DSN for process 0x713c Thread 0x71dc DBC 0x35cfc204 Jet'.

Comment: @rene above connection string is locally running totally fine,but i want to pass absolute path

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/295297/prb-error-message-0x80004005-general-error-unable-to-open-registry-key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In web.config

```
<connectionStrings>    
   <add name="localconnection" connectionString="Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)} ;pwd=12345; DBQ="/>
</connectionStrings>
```

In .aspx file

```
string Connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["localconnection"].ConnectionString + Server.MapPath("//abc//pqr//xyz//abc.mdb");
OdbcConnection SGemsConn = new OdbcConnection(Connection);
```